# Estrutura condicional (if else) javascript

Tags: javascript, html, if, condição, else

Estou estudando JavaScript e estou com o seguinte problema:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pr-BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Nacionalidade</title>
</head>
<body>
    De onde você é?
    <input type="text" name="nac" id="nac">
    <input type="button" value="Verificar" onclick="verif()">
    <div id="res">

    </div>
    <script>
        var nac = document.getElementById('nac')
        var res = document.getElementById('res')
        function verif(){
            if (nac == 'Brasil'){
               res.innerHTML = `Você é brasileiro `
            }else {
                res.innerHTML = `Você é estrangeiro `
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Ao executar a, resposta é sempre a da estrutura else, não importa o que o usuário digite, não consegui identificar o problema.

Comment: apenas adicione ao lado do `nac` , `.value` vai ficar assim `nac.value`

Comment: Deu certo alguma resposta para você Alef?

Comment: Deu sim, vou continuar fazendo testes pra fixar a matéria, logo eu volto com mais dúvidas, rsrs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisa pegar o valor ***dentro da função***, porque, da maneira que está fazendo somente a primeira vez que a página carrega o valor é alterado e depois não mais, na verdade também faltou especificar a propriedade `value` que pega o valor do `</input>` sendo assim dois problemas, ***exemplo***:

```js
function carai() {
  var nac = document.getElementById('nac').value  
  if (nac === 'Brasil') {
    res.innerHTML = `Você é brasileiro `
  } else {
    res.innerHTML = `Você é estranjeiro `
  }
}
```

```html
De onde você é?
<input type="text" name="nac" id="nac">
<input type="button" value="Verificar" onclick="carai()">
<div id="res">
```

---

Um outra forma de resolver o problema é resgatar somente a referencia e dentro da função chamar a propriedade `value` que assim também o dado é atualizado:

```js
var nac = document.getElementById('nac');
function carai() {  
  if (nac.value === 'Brasil') {
    res.innerHTML = `Você é brasileiro `
  } else {
    res.innerHTML = `Você é estranjeiro `
  }
}
```

```html
De onde você é?
<input type="text" name="nac" id="nac">
<input type="button" value="Verificar" onclick="carai()">
<div id="res">
```

***Observação:*** na comparação utilize três iguais (`===`) para além de testar tipo também teste o valor.